# Can't share the image. Meta og:image doesn't work. (Laravel + VueJs)

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, meta-tags, sharing

In my controller in have a method

```
public function collage(Request $request, Collage $collage){
    return view('collage' , [
        'collage_id' => $request->route('id'),
        'src' => 'http://mysite.ru/images/collages/'.$collage->find($request->route('id'))->collage_path
    ]);
}
```

and in collage.blade.php meta

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{$src}}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{$src}}" />
<link rel="image_src" href="{{$src}}" />
```

Also i use vue-social-sharing ( https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing )

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div v-if="collageSrc" class="col-md-12 collage">
            <img class="img-responsive" :src="this.collageSrc"/>


            <social-sharing :url="url"
                            title="test"
                            description="test"
                            quote="Vue is a progressive framework for building user interfaces."
                            hashtags="#test"
                            twitter-user="test"
                            inline-template>
                <div>
                    <network network="facebook">
                        <i name="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
                    </network>
                    <network network="telegram">
                        <i class="fa fa-telegram"></i> Telegram
                    </network>
                </div>
            </social-sharing>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 collage" v-else>
            <h1>you image is preparing...</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        name: 'collage',
        props:['id'],
        data: function(){
            return {
                collageWaiter: this.getCollageSrc(),
                collageSrc: '',
                url : '',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getCollageSrc(){

                const self = this;

                axios.get('/api/generate?id='+this.id)
                    .then(function(result){
                        self.collageSrc = result.data;
                        self.url = "http://compgen.ru/collage/" + self.id;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I don't understand how to include my image to tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{$src}}" />
```

for image to ensure that the picture is also transferred to the social network

Comment: you can't. blade is on server side. Vue is on client side. this is precisely why people use [server side rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html)

Comment: but if i will be use next.js i will have to rewrite all my project. This is true ?

Comment: for Vue, it's called nuxtjs. not rewrite, but moving all the vue related codes into nuxt. and you will need to use nodejs on the server side to run nuxtjs. it's not simple

Comment: In order to just add a meta tag, I need to redo the application and do server rendering on node.js. Is there no easier way?

Comment: another way is called prerendering. php also can do server side rendering using V8js but i would expect it to be very unstable. here's some related tutorials  https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/11/06/vue-js-laravel-server-side-rendering/ . https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/04/09/single-page-app-seo/ .